# Object has no attribute - HyperlinkedRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to add hyperlinks to a list of "postings" that have a specific "category" ID

The URL that I am trying to build is for /categories/

models.py

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    ....
    idcategories = models.AutoField(db_column='idCategories', primary_key=True)

class Postings(models.Model):
    idpostings = models.AutoField(db_column='idPostings', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    idcategories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, db_column='idCategories')  # Field name made lowercase.
    ....
```

serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    postings = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='postings-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Categories
        fields = ('url', 'idcategories', 'categoriesname', 'categoryimageurl', 'postings')
```

views.py

```
url(r'postings/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', postings_detail, name='postings-detail'),
```

I have the appropriate views set up, which work if I remove the HyperlinkedRelatedField on the CategorySerializer

Essentially I want:

```
JSON:
categoryname : <name>,
postings : [<list_of_postings>]
```

So with the above code, I get the following error:

**AttributeError at /categories/
'Categories' object has no attribute 'postings'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default DRF will look at a related objects through the postings name which you don't have in your model.

Either set the idcategories `related_name` to "postings" or use the source serializer's field's argument `source` in the serializer's postings and set it to "postings_set".

Comment: I was basing my code on the example from DRF [link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/) and it doesn't seem like they used related_name

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-information-to-our-model < it's there